# Next.js dynamic routes with Firestore collection

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, ecmascript-6, next.js

I'm looking for a way to have a dynamic route that displays for every document in a Firestore collection using Server-side Rendering.

For example, a document called `foo` would exist at `test.com/foo` under the `[doc]` page component. Any time a document is added, it should be able to be accessed through its respective URL.

I've tried [this](https://leerob.io/blog/nextjs-firebase-serverless) method but I haven't been able to get it to work.
I've also tried implementing `getServerSideProps` but have not had much success, any pointers would be appreciated.

Code from the method above as follows:

under `pages/api/[doc].js`

```
export default (req, res) => {
  db.collection("docs")
    .doc(req.query.name)
    .get()
    .then((doc) => {
      res.json(doc.data());
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res.json({ error });
    });
};
```

under `pages/[shoal].jsx`

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import useSWR from "swr";

const fetcher = async (...args) => {
  const res = await fetch(...args);

  return res.json();
};

function Doc() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { name } = router.query;
  const { data } = useSWR(`/api/${name}`, fetcher);

  if (!data) {
    return "Loading...";
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Title: {data.title}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Doc;
```

Comment: What does not work with the method in that link any errors or something??

Comment: The name variable is undefined when console logged, and the returned res.json() in the fetcher function is empty

Comment: In that case you should share a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of that function so we can see what's wrong with it.

Comment: Added into my question!

Comment: Can you try using getServerSideProps as in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/DharmarajX24/d5d32f999faa91a749711b705d99698d)?

Comment: It seems to return a 404 error

Comment: Perhaps the doc does not exist? Try `console.log(doc.data())` before returning props

Comment: nothing logged to console at all, will have a poke around to see if I'm missing anything obvious. The document definitely exists in the Firestore collection, just checked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236764/discussion-between-jl98-and-dharmaraj).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `getServerSideProps`:

```
export const getServerSideProps = async (ctx) => {
  const doc = await db.collection("docs").doc(ctx.query.id).get()
  const data = doc.data()
  if (!data) return { notFound: true };
  return { props: { data } };
};

function Doc({data}) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { name } = router.query;

  if (!data) {
    return "Loading...";
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Title: {data.title}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Doc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution.

```
const { data } = useSWR(api ? '/api/${name}' : null, fetcher);
```

Conditionally fetch the data if your variable is defined, if not, don't pass a URL string, better yet; you can conditionally consider the fetcher for usage also.

```
const { data } = useSWR(name ? '/api/${name}' : null, name ? fetcher : null);
```